# Display Json in console on page when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spring-boot, react-native

I am currently getting JSON from my back end server and displaying it in my console. I am trying to display the JSON in the console in raw form on a webpage when the submit button is clicked for testing purposes. Is there an easy way to go about this? I am currently just changing window, but the data in the console isn't even showing up in postman.

Maybe I can display the data in a box underneath the form?

**Please see my React code below**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Card,Form,ButtonGroup,Button,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

export default class MovieList extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
var config = { headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}};
this.state = this.startState;
}
startState = {id: ""};


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = {
      id: this.state.id
    }

    axios.get("http://localhost:8082/movies/" + this.state.id, this.config)
      .then(res => {
        window.location = "/retrieve" //This line of code will redirect you once the submission is succeed
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
        JSON.stringify(res)
        JSON.stringify(res.data)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error has been caught: " + error);
                console.log(error);
                console.trace();
            });

  }
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      id: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
  const {id} = this.state
    return (
    <Card className = {"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
      <Card.Header> Get Json </Card.Header>
      <Form>
      <Card.Body>
      <Form.Group as = {Col}>
      <Form.Label> Customer ID </Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
      type = "test"
      placeholder = "Enter ID"
      value={id}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
       />
      <Form.Text className = "text-muted" >
      Press Get Json to receive JSON Data
      </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group >
      </Card.Body>
      <Card.Footer style = {{"textAlign": "right"}}>
      <Button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}
      size = "m"
      variant = "success"
      type = "submit" >
      Get Json
      </Button>
      </Card.Footer>
      </Form>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

**Please see my server side below**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE}, allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieResource {

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/{movieId}")
    public Movie getMovieInfo(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {
        MovieSummary movieSummary = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "?api_key=" +  apiKey, MovieSummary.class);
        return new Movie(movieId, movieSummary.getTitle(), movieSummary.getOverview());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to test then using the console seems like it would be good enough but if you want to store it on the page I'd create a stateful variable like `rawResponse`. When you get the data back from the API you can update that variable to contain the json (you probably need to stringify the json first to turn it into a string).

Then you have some conditional rendering in your page to display that json like this:

```js
{rawResponse != "" && <pre>{rawResponse}</pre>}
```

that simply renders the contents of `rawResponse` in a "pre" tag which should format it like it's code or something. If you're unfamiliar with what that line of code does you can look up "conditional rendering in react".